# Make a relative-positioned block element the same size as its contained absolute-positioned element

Tags: css, position

Ok, I'm trying to take several divs and all their content, and stack them on top of each other and make the containing div (#stack) appear in the normal flow of things via the following method:

CSS:

```
#stack
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
#stack div
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="stack">
    <div>
        <img src="images/1.jpg">
        <p>
            First Image
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/2.jpg">
        <p>
            Second Image
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/3.jpg">
        <p>
            Third Image
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/4.jpg">
        <p>
            Fourth Image
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which works, except now div#stack has a width/height of 0.  I would like it to be the same size as its largest child.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are taking the inner divs out of the document's flow with `position: absolute;`, the outer div cannot in any case stretch to the dimensions of the biggest child. You have to use javascript to achieve that effect. If you're familiar with jQuery, you could use something like this:

```
var w = false, h = false;

$('#stack div').each(function() {
    w = $(this).width() > w || !w ? $(this).width() : w;
    h = $(this).height() > h || !h ? $(this).height() : h;
});

$('#stack').css({
    width: w,
    height: h
});
```

Comment: Would you happen to know of a different way to achieve this (e.g. without taking them out of the document flow)?

Comment: Nope, to overlay elements above other requires you to take them out of the flow - that's the whole point. So javascript is your best bet to get it working properly.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! I just learning jQuery and was on my way to this same solution but was missing a thing or two found by your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the exact requirements, Javascript isn't necessary. Floats are also taken out of the flow, but can be contained.

Answer (score 0):

Setting position:absolute takes the node out of the flow, which is why the parent, not having any flowed content, gets dimensions of 0x0.

If your server code (e.g., PHP) knows about these images, you could calculate the maximum width and the maximum height among them and set the height/width of the parent appropriately.

Or, as Tatu says, you can use JavaScript and do it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the width of the `#stack` to shrink-wrap its children as well, or are you just concerned about its height? I'm assuming the latter, since you explicitly put `display: block` on it.

Because in that case, it is possible to do it just with CSS:

```
#stack {
    overflow: hidden;
    _zoom: 1;
}       
#stack div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
}
```

I added the `_zoom: 1` to trigger `hasLayout` in IE6. You can change that to your preferred method (e.g. in a separate IE6 stylesheet), or leave it out altogether if you don't need to support IE6.

In Opera, you can make the `#stack` shrink-wrap its children entirely (i.e. in width as well) when you float the stack (or `display: inline-block`) and add `width: 100%` to the child divs. I don't know if that's because of a bug in Opera, a bug in the other browsers, or just a difference due to a vague spec.